# Conditional probability with $5$ sided dice

Tags: probability

**Question**:
In Brooklyn people play a fair dice with $5$ sides, numbered $1,2,3,4,5$.
Jack rolls the dice over and over again. What is the probability that the results $2$ or $4$ will come up before the result $5$?

**What We want to understand**
We saw 2 solutions which we didn't understand:
The first one being: $\frac {0.2}{0.2+0.2+0.2}$ (we thought that $\Omega=${2,4,5} ???)
And the second solution is 
Let A be the desired prob. so we condition on the result of the first throw. $a=0.2 \cdot 0 + 0.4 \cdot 1 + 0.4 \cdot a $
Any explanations will be welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 0 (none of the ones listed): One of $2,4,5$ will come up first, from those three.  Which it is is equally likely.

Solution 1: probability that a 5 is rolled, conditioned on the probability that a 2,4, or 5 is rolled.  You actually want to subtract this from 1, or instead $\frac{0.2+0.2}{0.2+0.2+0.2}$.

Solution 2: Let $a$ be the desired probability, of winning.  After one roll, there is a $0.2$ chance of loss, a $0.4$ chance of winning, and a $0.4$ chance of rolling again, wherein you win with probability $a$ again.